# Duplicate username client side validation in Django

Tags: jquery, python, django, validation

I would like to do a client side validation on a username field when the user is registering for an account. This validation should check if the username has been taken before the user submits the form.

I have currently implemented basic client side validations using jQuery validate: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

What is the recommended approach to accomplish this in Django? Is it possible to integrate this solution with jQuery validate?

**Update** Below is my js and html code:

```
 <script>
    function getCookie(name) {
      var cookieValue = null;
      if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
          var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
          for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
              var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
              // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
              if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                  cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
      return cookieValue;
    }

    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');


    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
      // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
      return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
      }
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#register-form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
          username: {
            required: true,
            remote: {
              url: "/check-username",
              type: "post",
              data: {
                username: function() {
                  return $( "#id_username" ).val();
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="/accounts/register/" id="register-form" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {{form.username}}
  ...
</form>
```

Also, here is the view that does part of the validation:

```
def check_username(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', False)
    if not username:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Invalid username")
    return HttpResponse(User.objects.filter(username=username).exists())
```

Comment: You need to make an ajax call to your server with the current selected username and return a true or false if the username is already in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an adapted example of a remote validation from the documentation:

http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    username: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: {
        url: "/check-username",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          username: function() {
            return $( "#username" ).val();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Then all you need is a view that does

```
username = request.POST.get('username', None)
# probably you want to add a regex check if the username value is valid here
if not username:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest("Invalid username")
return HttpResponse(User.objects.filter(username=username).exists())
```

Comment: Ok thank you for this. But it seems like you have to submit the form for the validation to take place?

Comment: No, it will send a first ajax request that asks the server if the username is valid or not. Only if the server returns true and all other field's validation are also true the user form will (allowed to) be submitted.

Comment: Ok, got it. I just tried to implement this, but it seems like the ajax doesn't go through. In fact, now when there is an error with a field, the error message persists and doesn't get deleted upon successful entry.

Comment: Error I get when I go to developer tools: POST example.com/check-username 403 (FORBIDDEN) . I'm pretty sure this has to do with the csrf token but I'm not entirely sure how to pass it

Comment: Try adding a header to your ajax request, like "headers: {"X-CSRFToken": $.cookie('csrftoken')}"

Comment: I added the csrf as per the docs. The only other issue is that the last return statement should return a proper HTTP response, so it should look like this: return HttpResponse(User.objects.filter(username=username).exists())

Comment: But either way I'm not having any luck with the client side validation. Although the ajax call goes through and the function is executed :)

Comment: True regarding the HttpResponse, I somehow assumed you are using Django restframework. Add your client side code to the question otherwise people won't be able to help further.